# Review low quality answer whose question is already deleted

Tags: support, review

I'm referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5977932) answer. If the question is already deleted then why do we need to review the answer.

Comment: Please reload the review page and you'll understand ;-)